# Change the asterisk (heading identifier) to some other symbol in Org mode

Tags: org-mode

I know that outline mode works like this in Emacs org mode

```
* Heading 1  
** Heading 2
```

Is it possible to configure Emacs to take a different identifier than the `*`to identify headings?
I have a few files where I want to use a particular character (or character combination) where I have certain character combinations like `C %% MODULE` which mark the beginning of every module within the program.

So If I have a mechanism to use the `C %% MODULE` instead of `*` I do not have to add additional headings to enable the folding mechanism within my program.

Which file would I have to modify to have this functionality changed?

Just to provide more clarity, my code looks as shown below
[image]
I have developed this in org mode.  When I paste this into my system, I will have to manually delete the preceeding `*` and paste it.
But I was looking for a cleaner solution and if possible I could customize org-mode further to meet my requirements.

Comment: I'm confused about whether this is actually an org-mode question. Headings aside, are these files using org-mode syntax? Or do you just want to be able to use folding in some non-org files?

Comment: @Prasanna Can you please talk about the goal you want to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Sounds like the intent is to use some outline mode (for organization, folding?) for source code files -- not necessarily org-mode?

Comment: @KaushalModi, The intent is to fold the code to one level so that I can visually look at only one/two modules at a time. The file is 10,000+ lines of text and it might contain like 100+ modules. It would be neat and easier to organize it that way for me

Comment: @glucas, you may be right when u say that. I'm willing to do the leg work of modifying (by trial and error of course - i'm no expert) the piece of code in org-mode which identifies the headings (or outlines). This would make the review and understanding of the code easier

Comment: @phils, these are non-org files. They have an extension of PDTN (some fortran based system). But I do not mind creating the entire code in org mode - just as plain text and then copying them onto my target system.

Comment: @Prasanna Have a look at `outshine` package. I use that for same kind of 'module' navigation, folding, etc in non-org code files. Here's an [example](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-editing.el). The difference in this example is that `;;;`, `;;;;`, .. are used as 'module' delimiters. You can configure `outshine` to match the delimiters you want.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about `outline-mode` rather than `org-mode`, which is built on top of `outline-mode`.  If so, the least intensive option is probably to modify `outline-regexp` and friends.

Comment: Have a look also at the `hide-show` library to create your  own regexp for folding modules:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible in org-mode, but if you need just the folding feature, you may use `outline-mode` instead of `org-mode`, where you can change the value of `outline-regexp`.

```
(setq outline-regexp "C %% ")
```

Folding/unfolding are much less intuitive in `outline-mode` but you can add org-mode visibility cycling to outline mode with:

```
(add-hook 'outline-mode-hook
  (lambda () 
     (define-key outline-mode-map [(tab)] 'org-cycle)
     (define-key outline-mode-map [(shift tab)] 'org-global-cycle)))
```

Comment: The org mode visibility cycling hook doesn't seem to work. What could be wrong?. Pushing the `TAB` key just moves the text by 4 spaces :-(

Comment: @Prasanna Have you enabled `outline-mode`? What is TAB bound to (`C-h k TAB`)?

Comment: I have enabled the `outline-mode` (major mode). I do not know how to find the key-binding yet. I will find out and update you. I will also try the key binding in your comment to see if it works

Comment: @Prasanna `C-h k` (`describe-key`) **is** the command to find what function a key is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use org-bullets

https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets

```el
 (require 'org-bullets)
 (setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("☯" "○" "✸" "✿" "~"))
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

Comment: That just changes the *display*, right?

Comment: @phils I think that's the best bet? Because I think that actual changes to the file will break all kinds of regexps for headline matching.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the files in question *already* use a different syntax. The question *is* a little confusing, though.

Comment: I already use the expression shown above, in my .emacs file. This is not what I want. I want to use `C %% MODULE` to mark the line as a heading one. I do not need levels too. Just even one level is good.

Answer (score 0):

In outline-minor-mode, to get `<tab>` and `S-<tab>` to act a bit more like org-mode:

```
(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (define-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'outline-cycle)
        (define-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "S-<iso-lefttab>")
          '(lambda ()
             (interactive)
             (save-excursion
               (goto-char (point-min))
               (outline-show-all)
               (outline-hide-leaves))))))
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: The user shares his outline-mode hook for code folding, this is as addition to the discussion in the comments. Perhaps it will be more complete if the other links and examples referred to in the comments be added as an edit to this answer.