# It is possible to display numbers at the beginning of headerlines instead of asterisks when editing/viewing org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

For example, a simple org-mode file like this:

```
* Header one
** Sub-header one
** Sub-header two
* Header two
** Sub-header one
```

After exporting this org-mode file into html file, the html in browser will be like:

```
1. Header one
1.1 Sub-header one
1.2 Sub-header two
2. Header two
2.1 Sub-header one
```

But I do rarely convert org files into html files, I do a lot of note-takings from a webpage or book, so it is very friendly if the org-mode buffer can show the numbers like the html file in browser directly instead of just asterisks. Of course, when inserting header/subheader or deleting header/subheader, org-mode should change the numbers according the context just like the list in org-mode.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: See [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26180/15748).

Comment: @Basil No, it's not related.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was, "you may be interested in..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [lrkry](https://www.reddit.com/user/lrkry)'s answer at [reddit.com/r/emacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6crtzw), I'll post his/her answer here if anyone sees this.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode org-numbers-overlay-mode
  "Add overlays to org headings which number them"
  nil " *1." nil
  (let ((hooks '(after-save-hook
                 org-insert-heading-hook))
        (funcs '(org-promote
                 ;; org-cycle-level
                 org-promote-subtree
                 org-demote
                 org-demote-subtree
                 org-move-subtree-up
                 org-move-subtree-down
                 org-move-item-down
                 org-move-item-up
                 org-cut-subtree
                 org-insert-todo-heading
                 org-insert-todo-subheading
                 org-meta-return
                 org-set-property)))
    (if org-numbers-overlay-mode
        (progn
          (org-numbers-overlay-update)
          (dolist (fn funcs)
            (advice-add fn :after #'org-numbers-overlay-update))
          (dolist (hook hooks)
            (add-hook hook #'org-numbers-overlay-update)))
      (progn
        (dolist (fn funcs)
          (advice-add fn :after #'org-numbers-overlay-update))
        (dolist (hook hooks)
          (remove-hook hook #'org-numbers-overlay-update))
        (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'type 'org-number)))))
(defun org-numbers-overlay-update (&rest args)
  (when org-numbers-overlay-mode
    (let ((continue t)
          (levels (make-vector 10 0))
          (any-unnumbered (member "UNNUMBERED" (org-buffer-property-keys))))
          (save-excursion
        (widen)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (or (outline-on-heading-p)
            (outline-next-heading))
        (overlay-recenter (point-max))
        (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'type 'org-number)
        (while continue
          (let* ((detail (org-heading-components))
                 (level (- (car detail) 1)))
            (when (or (not any-unnumbered)
                      (org-entry-get (point) "UNNUMBERED" 'selective))
              (let* ((lcounter (1+ (aref levels level)))
                     text)
                (aset levels level lcounter)
                (loop for i from (1+ level) to 9
                      do (aset levels i 0))
                (loop for i across levels
                      until (zerop i)
                      do (setf text (if text
                                        (format "%s.%d" text i)
                                      (format " %d" i))))
                (let  ((o (make-overlay (point) (+ (point) (car detail)) nil t t)))
                  (overlay-put o 'type 'org-number)
                  (overlay-put o 'evaporate t)
                  (overlay-put o 'after-string text)))))
          (setq continue (outline-next-heading))
          )))))
```

You can either add `(provide 'org-numbers-overlay)` line at the end of the code and save all of them to a file, then use it as a package, or you can just add this after that code snippet in your `init.el/.emacs`

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (org-numbers-overlay-mode)))
```

In case the author updates the source code, this is the original [source code link](https://github.com/larkery/emacs/blob/master/site-lisp/org-numbers-overlay.el).

Comment: This version of solution will make `emacsclient -a "" -n -c -e "(org-capture)" fail to lanuch emacs (at least for terminal emacs). org-num.el file from orgmode v9.3 supports this feature.

Answer (score 4):

There is a package called [org section numbers](https://github.com/marcowahl/org-section-numbers) that does exactly this.

Comment: It is fine, but not good, it is not dynamic, if you insert header, the new header will still start with asterisk instead of numbers , if you delete header, the numbers of context will not change dynamically. You have to execute `org-section-numbers-toggle` repeatedly to make the numbers change.