# Display another symbol than asterisks in org headings

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, font-lock

I would like to change the way headings render while still using the `*` to type headings (so this question is distinct from [Change the asterisk (heading identifier) to some other symbol in Org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26180/change-the-asterisk-heading-identifier-to-some-other-symbol-in-org-mode))

I want this

```
* One
** Two
*** Three
```

to render as

```
# One
## Two
### Three
```

The closest I can get is by using `org-bullets` and changing the `org-bullets-bullet-list` symbols, but that conceals the initial symbols with spaces:

```
# One
 # Two
  # Three
```

---

Preferably, I would not need to use use the `org-bullets` package and just use a regex to replace the font face of the headings symbols. I found this snippet for changing `-` and `*` in plain lists to a `•`.

```
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^ +\\([-*]\\) "
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "•"))))))
```

When I try to modify it for headings it does not change the appearance of the headings and does not throw any error (maybe there is some later applied highlighting in org-mode that overwrites the regex substitution? or because I am just using a single `#` to replace possibly more than one `*`?).

```
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^*+ "
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#"))))))
```

I am using Emacs through the Spacemacs distribution.

Comment: You might like https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compose-region` does not solve your problem. Use the text property `display` instead and put the string you like atop the header leader. You can let you guide by `org-bullets-mode` for that.

If you want to try that approach copy the following lines into your init file and re-start emacs.

Activate `org-bullet-mode` for replacing `*` with `#` in header leaders.

```el
(defcustom org-bullet ?\#
  "Replacement for * as header prefixes."
  :type 'characterp
  :group 'org)

(define-minor-mode org-bullet-mode
    "Bullet for org-mode"
  nil nil nil
  (let* ((keyword
           `(("^\\*+ "
              (0 (let* ((level (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0) 1)))
           (when (> level 1)
             (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (- (match-end 0) 2) 'display (make-string (1- level) org-bullet)))
           (put-text-property (- (match-end 0) 2) (- (match-end 0) 1) 'display (string org-bullet))
                   nil))))))
    (if org-bullet-mode
        (progn
          (font-lock-add-keywords nil keyword)
          (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (font-lock-remove-keywords nil keyword)
        (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
      )))
```

You can activate `org-bullet-mode` automatically when starting `org-mode` with the following entry in your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-bullet-mode)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The reason I mentioned that i prefer not to use `org-bullets` is because I prefer to display all heading symbols when I narrow to subtree and deindent (so it doesn't look like the heading is indented from the left margin). I can use `org-hide-leadings-stars` for this, but didn't find a way to do use it with `org-bullets`, do you know of one?

Comment: @JoelOstblom `org-bullet-mode` from my answer displays all heading symbols, i.e., `**` is replaced by `##` and so on. That is what `make-string` does.

Comment: For me, all `*` are replaced with `#` (for all heading levels), but only the last heading symbol is displayed, the rest are hidden unless the cursor is over them. This is the default behavior for `org-bullets` on my spacemacs installation, so there is some other setting I need to tweak I think to get the same behavior as when disabling `org-hide-leading-stars` when not using `org-bullets`.

Comment: @JoelOstblom Once again. Have you really tried the code of my answer? That is **not** the code of `org-bullets`! The code above is everything you need you don't need `org-bullets`. You can paste the above code into your init file and are done. Add also  `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-bullet-mode)` if you want to use `org-bullet-mode` the code whenever your buffer is in `org-mode`. Maybe, the name difference between `org-bullets-mode` and `org-bullet-mode` is far too small to be easily recognized. Sorry about that.

Comment: Agh! Sorry, I tried your code but didn't restart emacs (I missed your edit). And yes, I misread `org-bullet-mode` as `org-bullets-mode` so I thought that was the reason it was not working. I tried it again now and it works as I want except for when I use `org-hide-leading-stars`, which now hides all `#` of the headings instead of hiding all but the last `#` (the exception being first level headings, where the lone `#` is displayed). Do you see this as well? Thanks again and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JoelOstblom I've split the stars. That should solve the problem with `org-hide-leading-stars`. By the way "I've split the stars." sounds rather bombastic -- like something the next generation Death Star from Star Wars episodes could do;-)).

Comment: Haha, that does indeed sound bombastic =) Thanks for the update, I tried the new version but it gathers multiple headings on the same row instead of having one heading per row. Could there be a newline missing somewhere?

Comment: @JoelOstblom Hm, strange it is working as expected for me. With `emacs -q`, `M-x package-initialize`, emacs-version: 25.1.50, org-version: 9.1.6

Comment: I tried with a config file with only your code (`emacs -q -l custom-init.el`), and it worked. Then I tried with my spacemacs config again and now it worked! Hard to say what the error was previously (my money is on user related...). Thanks so much for you help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant approach, but this appears to work

```
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^\\(*\\)"
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#"))))))

  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^\\*\\(*\\)"
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#"))))))

  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^*\\*\\(*\\)"
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#"))))))

  (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
    '(("^*\\*\\*\\(*\\)"
    (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "#"))))))
```

The above snippet would change `*` at headings level 1-4 into `#` and can be extended to as many levels as needed.